# Getting error ORA-00904 when trying to add column in interactive report

Tags: oracle, report, apex, interactive

I created an interactive report based on a SQL-Query, I then wanted to insert another value from the table into this SQL query.
However, when I tried to do this I got the following error: ORA-00904: "D". "SPID": invalid ID.

I have already googled it and it says it could be because the wrong column name was entered or it would be solved if an alias was used, which I have already tried but still get the same error.
I have also run the SQL query in the SQL command and it shows me the correct result.
So what could be the cause of the error?

This is the SQL query on which the interactive report is based:

```
select f.FPID, f.TITLE,f.DATE,f.STATE 
FROM FORM f
left outer join MANAGER m on m.MID=f.MID
left outer join USERS u on u.UUID=m.UUID
where lower(u.username)=lower(:session_user_name);
```

With this query, the report is displayed normally.
However, when I try to retrieve another column from the Form table for the report, I get the error described above.

```
select f.FPID, f.TITLE,f.DATE,f.STATE, **f.SPID**
FROM FORM f
left outer join MANAGER m on m.MID=f.MID
left outer join USERS u on u.UUID=m.UUID
where lower(u.username)=lower(:session_user_name);
```

Comment: The error message references d.SPID.  Your query adds a column f.SPID.  Did you perhaps typo your alias name when you entered the query in the interactive report?

Comment: I already checked it, in the report I add the column f.SPID

Comment: Then where does the error message for d.SPID come from?

Comment: the added column does not differ from the others

Comment: Then the error is coming from somewhere else.  Oracle isn't going to just make up something in the error message.  It's complaining about a query that references a column `d.SPID`.  If the query you're looking at doesn't have a `d.SPID` reference, it must not be the query that is throwing the error.